# ksh93 return code 127 on function

Tags: background, ksh

I wrote a small function to submit a command with a timeout in ksh. If I use "ps", in some case the function return 127! ksh (AIX, 88) doesn't have this behavior, but ksh93 (AIX) does.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93
function mysubmit
{
eval "$@" &
pid=$!
/usr/bin/ps -p $pid
wait $pid
rc=$?
return $rc
}
output="$(mysubmit true)"
echo "RC 1=$?"
mysubmit true
echo "RC 2=$?"
```

Execution:

```
# ./test2.sh
RC 1=127
      PID    TTY  TIME CMD
RC 2=0
```

If I change ksh93 to ksh, it works. If I change "ps -p $pid" to "kill -0 $pid", it works. If I remove the background processing (&), it works. In my case I changed "ps -p $pid" to "kill -0 $pid", it solved the issue, but I don't understand the RC=127 behavior at all...!

Note: my real "mysubmit" is more complex, I tried to simplify it as much as I could to extract the behavior only.

Any ideas?

Comment: In a POSIX shell, 127 is returned for *command not found*.  I can simply reproduce with `mysubmit trueth` instead of `mysubmit true`.

Comment: I know 127 is "command not found", but in this case the command IS found, and event $output contains the rigth output. Only the return code is bogus, and if I change "ps" to "kill -0" to detect if the process is still running, the return code goes back to 0 - the expected behavior. So Why is the script returning 127 when all command are existing and working?

Comment: I'm a bit clueless here. What happens if you leave out the `ps` command entirely? Or put it inside `(` `)`?  Sadly, some releases of ksh93 behave oddly with command substitution and background processes, and I don't have access to AIX here.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. What version of ksh93 do you have? `ksh --version` for me returns `version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`

Comment: ksh93 version:   version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2009-05-01
For the other question: if I put the "ps" in () (subshell), it solves the problem.
Do you have any references for this statement:
"Sadly, some releases of ksh93 behave oddly ", I would read about that... or maybe just your personnal experience.

Comment: Update: I just tested it with ksh 93u+ on Linux, I don't have the problem, so it seems to be related to ksh93 version. Bottom line, IMHO, it's a "bug", solved in more recent version of ksh93.